# Can planetshine make the sky darker?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

While discussing an artist's representation of a moon in an alien sky, I commented that it's unrealistic for the dark side of the moon to make the sky darker. Someone else said that they had seen this in real life with our moon.

Since planetshine is reflected light from a planet reflecting again on another object, it seems logical that it can only make things (including the sky) brighter.

Can planetshine from the dark side of a moon make the sky darker? Can an optical illusion make it *appear* darker?

Comment: The fact that the moon occludes starlight from behind it would compete with planetshine reflection.

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. If this is a physical phenomenon, where is the evidence? An artist's impression, and someone else's recollection, are not sound evidence. If it is an optical illusion, it is not physics.

Comment: @sammygerbil If I had physical evidence, I wouldn't be asking. Someone has said it's possible. This is counter-intuitive to me, but that doesn't mean it's false. I don't want to be "that knee-jerk guy".

Comment: "Someone has said it is possible" is not a good reason for asking a question on this site. Someone might say it is possible for 1+1 to equal 3, but that is no reason why anyone should bother to explain why it isn't possible. But if there is some evidence, it becomes a worthwhile question.

Comment: Observation is evidence.

Comment: @sammygerbil This is exactly how science works. Someone says "If I drop a light weight and a heavy weight off the Tower of Pisa at the same time, the heavy one will hit the ground first." Someone else comes along and says "Both weights will hit the ground at the same time." The first person says "That's obviously wrong!" A third person says "Let's test it!" I believe that planetshine will _always_ lighten_ the sky and never darken it. However, I don't know everything, so I could be wrong.

Comment: During a lunar eclipse the sky gets darker... Not that planetshine factors in there at all.

Comment: @CJDennis So test it then. Make an observation.